# Как сделать чтобы изображение img капчи не обрезалось и не выходило за пределы div

Tags: php, html, css, netcat

Обрезается изображение капчи на сайте.
Как сделать чтобы изображение `img` капчи не обрезалось и не выходило за пределы div?

Пробовал задавать `max-width; max-height; overflow: auto; overflow: hidden;` отступы - не помогает.

```
<div>
  <input type="hidden" name="nc_captcha_hash" value="81f71cc057e9441045cae241bc990505">
  <img name="nc_captcha_img" src="/netcat/modules/captcha/img.php?code=81f71cc057e9441045cae241bc990505">
</div>
```

[image: Обрезаются буквы и цифры слева и справа]

Нужно чтобы captcha отображалась полностью без обрезки

На этой странице видно проблему cdc-msk.ru/feedback

Comment: приложите ссылку на сайт или код который воспроизводит проблему

Comment: Частенько в настройках капчи есть размер воспроизводимой картинки.

Comment: На этой странице видно проблему http://www.cdc-msk.ru/feedback/

Comment: это дело в каптче

Comment: Duoxx, а как это исправить?